# Is it possible to use RPy/RPy2 in a Geoprocessing Script that is exposed as a GP Task on ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing, r, python-2.6

Is it possible to publish a Script tool that uses the RPy/RPy2 module (or more generally any Python-to-R link) to ArcGIS Server 10 SP2? If so, what specifically do I need to do, i.e. Install R on the server machine(s). Thanks.

Comment: I changed it to an answer, but should I re-post the code and workflow from the document so that it is available on GIS.SE? The link in the future may not be available.

Comment: I think it would be nice to add not only a link, but also a short summary of your findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some extensive searching has yielded *exactly* what I was looking for. [See Here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=cXVhcnRpY3NvbHV0aW9ucy5jb218cXVhcnRpY19jb21wYW55X2ludGVybmV0fGd4OjJhNWQwYTk1NzE0NGU1NzU). Originally obtained from [here](http://www.quarticsolutions.com/in-the-news/integrationofrstatisticalpackage).

Comment: This link is off ! can you re post the good link ?

Comment: Please don't just post links but include the main ideas into your answer. This is the only way to insure that your answers don't suffer "link rot".